# Can't re-size image properly in node js

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, sails.js, image-resizing

I used different module for the image re-size

These are

- **imagemagick**
- **easyimage**

Basically I want to replace with existing.Lets say existing image is **header.jpg** .User can change that image as they want.But case is when add new image and it resize according to the **header.jpg 's** dimension.Finally it dimension always decrease.I need keep **header.jpg's** dimension when whatever image user uploaded.I hope my idea is clear.

Here is code which i tried

```
    var dePath='/templates/img/';
    var headerExist ='/templates/img/header.jpg';
    var headerDimensions = sizeOf(headerExist);

    console.log(headerDimensions);

    req.file('file').upload({
        dirname: require('path').resolve(dePath)
    },function (err, uploadedFiles) {
        if (err) return res.send(500, err);


        fs.unlink(headerExist, function (err) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            console.log("success!");
            console.log('test');

            fs.rename(uploadedFiles[0].fd, dePath+'headertemp.jpg', function (err) {
                if (err) return res.send(err);

                im.resize({
                    srcPath:dePath+'headertemp.jpg',
                    dstPath: headerExist,
                    width: headerDimensions.width
                }, function(err, stdout, stderr){
                    if (err) console.log(err + 'ff');

                    fs.unlink(dePath+'headertemp.jpg', function (err) {
                        if (err) return console.error(err);
                        console.log("success!");
                        console.log('test');
                        res.send('ok');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

If you know any better module for my situation.then let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: okay how did header.jpg come in existance? user uploaded it or it is already in system by default?

Comment: It is existing one. User can change it as they wish. Yeh  it's already in system by default